# Getting zeros with SSE Shift

Tags: c, sse

I have this code:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int i;
    __m128 x_v, y_v, e_v;
    __m128i mask_v;

    float x[8]={1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,4.0f};
    float y[8]={1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,4.0f};
    int exp0mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    for(i=0; i+3<4; i+=4) {
        x_v = _mm_loadu_ps(x+i);
        y_v =  _mm_loadu_ps(y+i);
        mask_v = _mm_set1_epi32(exp0mask);
        e_v = _mm_and_ps(x_v,  _mm_castsi128_ps(mask_v));
        e_v = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_srli_epi32(_mm_castps_si128(e_v), 23));
        _mm_storeu_ps(y+i, e_v);
        printf("%f\n", y[i]);
        printf("%f\n", y[i+1]);
        printf("%f\n", y[i+2]);
        printf("%f\n", y[i+3]);
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

The values in `x[i]` (a float array) are not zero. I have observed, that the zero-result happens after the shift-operation `_mm_srli_epi32`. But why is that so and what can I do?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Why don't you look at `e_v` in your debugger as you step through the code and see what's actually going on ? Much more effective than guesswork.

Comment: I was curious on this and managed to do a working example, I realized then that the code is a bit weird since for instance it loads the values from `y` and never use them. Or it shows the values from `x` and never writes them. I eddited such that it makes some sense, but I'm still not sure what it does.

Comment: @Emilien: That does not seem to be the genuine code. At least I cannot imagine that to be the case given the weird loop construct and the way the always-zero loop counter is used.

Comment: After the shift right logical, the number (interpreted as a float)  will be denormal. Make sure that a) You `printf()` with sufficient precision and b) Your processor is not set to DAZ or FTZ (does not treat denormals as zero).

Comment: @EOF: In particular, try printing with `%g` instead of `%f`.